# Angular2 template issue with double not (!!+)

Tags: javascript, templates, angular

Been smashing my head with this for a few hours, but I'm now pretty certain that it's an Angular2 issue, somewhere.

Scenario: I get tinyint in JSON from my PHP `"isLiked": "1"`. Because of JSON, the tinyint are understood as string instead of Booleans by Javascript, so i've been using the good ol' `!!+isLiked` to change it to a boolean.

In my Angular2 template I need to do :

`<i class="glyphicon  {{ (!(!!+post.isLiked) ) ? 'glyphicon-heart-empty' : 'glyphicon-heart'  }}"></i>`

This code used to work perfectly in Backbone with Underscore templates. But, it seems that Angular2 does something that changes the way !!+"0" is evaluated!

In Chrome console: 
`!!+"0"` returns `false`.

In Backbone+Underscore:
`<% !!+"0" %>` in a template shows `false`.

In Angular2:
`{{ !!+"0" }}` in a template shows `true`.

Here's a playground for it http://plnkr.co/E3YGYeQ5ZZIRh8JxsUN6 .

The `false` comes from a simple Javascript `document.write(!!+"0")` inside index.html, before Angular does anything.

The `true` is inside `src/app.ts` template.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I'm useless with Angular, but what happens if you write `post.isLiked == true` rather than `!!+post.isLiked`?

Comment: Won't work as post.isLiked is actually "0" or "1" (strings) and not true or false.

Comment: Try it though? Works in JavaScript

Comment: I know it does, but I can't use it. My boss has a strict (and weird) policy that "booleans should match a check to `=== true` and `=== false`. He for some reason dislikes `== true` with a burning passion. Maybe it caused him issues earlier in life, who knows ? Point is, I have to manipulate my value to have an actual boolean, not a boolean-ish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular template syntax doesn't support full JavaScript syntax. 
Just move your code to a function and call it instead

```
<i class="glyphicon  {{ truthyCheck(+post.isLiked) ? 'glyphicon-heart-empty' : 'glyphicon-heart'  }}">
```

```
class MyComponent {
  trutyCheck(value):boolean {
    return !(!!+post.isLiked) ;
  }
}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PdmW0D7LTPV1Rl7Eq1l3?p=preview)

See also
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-statements

Comment: So there's no way to execute arbitrary javascript ? What if I want to console.log my post or something ? Creating a function in each component where i need to check one of my PHP provided boolean seems like a drag.

Comment: You can't call global functions like `console`, `window`, ... in the template. Create a function in the component/directive that does and call this function instead.

Comment: I guess i'll look at how to make a global directive now so I don't have to copy debug code (`console.log`) and boolean checking code everywhere..

Comment: @Growiel, "We write template expressions in a language that looks like JavaScript. Many JavaScript expressions are legal template expressions, but not all."  Read more about the limitations [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions).